# how to horizontally center active tab when scrolling past a certain point on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a responsive site and I want to add the following features on its mobile views.

1. Navbar has to be horizontally scrolling
2. Active tabs should be toggled when scrolling past certain points on the page
3. Active tabs should be centered on its horizontal scroller as you scroll past the corresponding sections on mobile devices

I'm taking this functionality from this banking site that's public domain (https://www.uob.com.sg/privilegebanking/wealth/invest/foreign-exchange-access.page

So far I've gotten points 1 and 2 done. I'm struggling with getting the tabs to scroll to the center on its horizontal scrollbar.

My code for doing that is as follows:

JS:

```
function activeHorizontal() {
    var navWidth = $('.sticky-nav').width()
    var activeFromLeft = $('.nav-tabs li.active').scrollLeft()
    var distToActiveFromRight = (navWidth/2) - (activeFromLeft);

    console.log(navWidth, activeFromLeft, distToActiveFromRight);
    $('.sticky-nav').animate({
        scrollLeft: activeFromLeft - distToActiveFromRight
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="sticky-navibar" class="container px-0">
   <div class="sticky-wrapper">
       <div class="sticky-nav no-mask scrolltabs-container col-4">
           <ul class="nav-heading nav nav-tabs nav-justified scrolltabs">
               <li class="active"><a href="#overview" title="Overview">Overview</a></li>
               <li class=""><a href="#benefits">Benefits</a></li>
               <li class=""><a href="#rewards">Exclusive Cash Rewards</a></li>
               <li class=""><a href="#getStarted">Get Started</a></li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Could someone please help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you add a bounty on your question...

Comment: Thanks @dalelandry though I came up with a solution for it last night. It seems to work. I’ll post it up shortly :)